# A reference request for the consistency of the parameters of an autoregressive process estimated through maximum likelihood

Tags: time-series, estimation, maximum-likelihood, econometrics

Let $y_t$ be modeled as an auto regressive process of order 1, that is

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{t} &= \alpha + \beta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}, \\
\epsilon_{t} &\stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(0,1).
\end{aligned}
$$

Given a sample $\{ y_1, \dots , y_n \}$I know how to find estimators for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ through maximum likelihood but I have never seen a proof of the consistency of the estimators.

What would be a good (modern) reference for the entire proof of the consistency of the maximum likelihood estimators in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption of normality it is straightforward to see that maximizing the log-likelihood $$\ell(\alpha, \beta, \sigma^2; y)=-\frac{T-1}{2}\log(2\pi)-\frac{T-1}{2}\log(\sigma^2)-\sum_{t=2}^T\frac{(y_t-\alpha-\beta_1y_{t-1})^2}{2\sigma^2}$$
w.r.t. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is equivalent to minimizing 
$$\sum_{t=2}^T(y_t-\alpha-\beta_1y_{t-1})^2$$
w.r.t. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the OLS problem. As such it suffices to show consistency of the OLS estimates which is quite standard.

Standard references for this are e.g. Hamilton's [Time Series Analysis](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html) or [Econometric Theory and Methods](https://www.amazon.de/Econometric-Theory-Methods-Russell-Davidson/dp/0195123727) by Davidson and MacKinnon.